# ModuleNotFoundError when running PySpark code that do Sentiment analysis

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, spark-streaming, user-defined-functions, sentiment-analysis

I have a spark streaming job that takes its streaming from Twitter API and I want to do Sentiment analysis on it

So I import vaderSentiment

and after that, I create the UDF function as shown below

```
def perform_sentiment_analysis(text):
    # Initialize VADER sentiment analyzer
    analyzer = SentimentIntensityAnalyzer()
    
    # Perform sentiment analysis on the text
    sentiment_scores = analyzer.polarity_scores(text)
    
    # Return the compound sentiment score
    return sentiment_scores['compound']

# Define a PySpark UDF for sentiment analysis using VADER
sentiment_analysis_udf = udf(perform_sentiment_analysis, StringType())
```

```
result_df = df.withColumn("sentiment_score", sentiment_analysis_udf("text"))
```

But there is an error when executing this "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'vaderSentiment'"

I try to work around and collect the text column and after that Join this with the dataframe that I have, it worked but it is not suitable for spark streaming